# Distance between two wireless mobile nodes

Tags: networking, mobile, distance, wireless, adhoc

I am currently trying to find the method or mechanism for calculating the distance between two wireless mobile nodes.

Let's say, there are 2 nodes (node B and C) coming in communication with node A. How can node A knows whether node B or node C is nearer than the other?

Is it possible to find it out by using RSSI? or are there any other mechanisms to calculate the distance?

I would appreciate any of your answers or comments.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How about using GPS? Most mobile devices have internal GPS support these days.
The RSSI will give you some indication of distance, but signal may have bounced around and penetrated several walls, so a stronger signal doesn't necessarily mean they are closer.
Another option is to use WiFi geolocation, which works pretty good assuming there are several other WiFi access points in the area. I use SkyHook and it works great:
http://www.skyhookwireless.com/location-technology/sdk.php